# Firebase identifica erróneamente un Int en lugar de un String - "Exception Error" en Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter

Mi base en Firebase es de a siguiente forma:

```
alimento
  -MCcU7UWMTzGLoYrfg
    cantidad: 3050
    lotesAlimento
      AAABBB: 1000
      AAACCC: 2050
```

Como puede observarse, la cantidad de alimento está dividida en diferentes lotes que tiene un Key que es la referencia del lote (_loteAlimento de tipo String) y la cantidad correspondiente a ese lote. Todo funciona muy bien, excepto cuando el usuario elige 1 como el idLote. En ese caso aparece el siguiente error:

```
Exception has occurred.
_TypeError (type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' of 'index')
```

Al parecer Firebase erróneamente está identificando el idLote como un Int en lugar de identificarlo como un String y no se como corregirlo.

La forma como estoy escribiendo la base es la siguiente:

```
Map<String, dynamic> _mapaValores = { "cantidad": _cantActualizada, "lotesAlimento/${_loteAlimento[i].toString()}": _cantLoteActualizado};
db.child('alimento/$idAlimento').update(_mapaValores);
```

Como ven, intenté forzar el valor de _loteAlimento a String en caso que fuera un número, pero no me funciona cuando el número es "1".

Donde se genera el error es al intentar leer los datos de la base en la siguiente función:

```
 Future<List<String>> cargarIdLotesAlimento() async {

    Query resp;
    final List<String> idLoteAlimentoList = new List(); 

    resp = db.child('alimento/$idAlimento/lotesAlimento');

    final snapshot = await resp.once();

    if (snapshot.value == null) return [];
    if (snapshot.value['error'] != null) return []; //AQUÍ SE GENERA EL ERROR

    snapshot.value.forEach((id, loteAlim){
      idLoteAlimentoList.add(id);
    });

    return idLoteAlimentoList;
}
```

[image: Error y Valor de la variable en ese momento (null)]

Lo extraño es que cuando el valor no es "1" sino "13" por ejemplo, Firebase si lo identifica correctamente como un String...

[image: Interpretación correcta en Firebase del valor "13" como un String]

Alguna idea de porqué sucede esto y cómo corregirlo?

Comment: agrega la parte como subes los datos a firebase , ahí está el problema, no cuando lo extraes.

Comment: Los subo como un Mapa. Está incluido en la pregunta

Comment: el problema es `_cantActualizada` ?

Comment: Nop... _cantActualizada y _cantLoteActualizado son double y se están registrando correctamente. El problema es en _loteAlimento[i] que es un String. De todas maneras internté forzarlo a .toString() pero no funciona. Cuando se graba en Firebase simplemente queda como un 1 y Firebase cree que es un Int

Comment: No se entiende que valor es que está viajando como INT a firebase , puedes aclarar eso ? en el mapa que pusiste veo esto  { "cantidad": _cantActualizada, "lotesAlimento/${_loteAlimento[i].toString()}": _cantLoteActualizado}; ,     esto `"lotesAlimento/${_loteAlimento[i].toString()}"`  es un string concatenado, a que valor te refieres?

Comment: Ok gracias. Al inicio está descrita la base... tiene dos keys (de tipo String) cantidad y lotesAlimento. El value de lotesAlimento tiene un Key que esla referencia de lote del Alimento (de tipo String y asignable por el usuario) y un value que es la cantidad (_cantLoteActualizado).  De esta forma, con un solo update actualizo tanto la cantidad como los lotes a los que pertenece. Entonces ese mapa es por ejemplo {"cantidad": 5, "lotesAlimento/ABC123": 5}. El problema es cuando ese numero de lote es 1... {"cantidad": 5, "lotesAlimento/1": 5}.

Comment: Allí, por alguna razón Firebase lo interpreta el 1 como Int y no como String, tal comosi lo hace cuando es ABC123 o un número más largo como el 13 que aparece en la pregunta

Comment: Será que se requiere definir loteAlimento a su vez como del tipo Map<String, dynamic>? Es posible hacer eso al definir MapaValores?

Comment: seguro que ahí es el error? snapshot.value['error'] ? no creo que deba marcar error ahí

Comment: En efecto no es que marque un error allí, sino que aparece un null y un valor (la cantidad) y no un key y un valor que es lo que está esperando (cómo está en el pantallazo que anexé con el valor 13)